# How to make a query that selects 1 unique data from 1 column but all the data from the other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a table* that is having 3 columns, ID, name and profession.

The table is having multiple professions with each a name(and id).

I can select everything and order it by profession so I can filter it in PHP with a foreach. But if i can already fix this with a Query, would help a lot to make a cleaner code.

So how do I make a query that can order all the names by profession, with profession showing once?

Those are examples when i fetch it in PHP.

What it outputs now;

```
array()
    {
    [0]=>array()
        {
         ["id"]=> "0"
         ["name"]=> "Alfred"
         ["profession"]=> "Barman"
        }
    [1]=>array()
        {
         ["id"]=> "1"
         ["name"]=> "Gus"
         ["profession"]=> "Barman"
        }
    }
```

What my idea of what it will output(doesn't have to be exact the same, but you get the idea where i want to go to);

```
 array()
    {
    [Barman]=>array()
        {
         ["name"]=> "Gus, Boris"
        }
    [Kelner]=>array()
        {
         ["name"]=> "Alfred, Walter White, Jesse Pinkman"
        }
    }
```

*[Table (name: employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWrX.png)

Comment: please explain better your problem, I am not able to understand

Comment: _“What I hope it will output”_ … makes little sense to begin with. You can not have the same array key (`name`)  occur more than once inside a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can come close with `group_concat()`:

```
select profession, group_concat(name separator ',') as names
from t
group by profession;
```

If you actually want a JSON response, then your question should be clear about that.  MySQL does not (otherwise) support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a JSON array with `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`:

```
select profession, json_arrayagg(name) as names
from mytable
group by profession
```

This generates one row per `profession`, with a JSON array that contains all corresponding names in a column called `names`.

We can get closer to the actual result you want with:

```
select json_objectagg(profession, names) as result
from (
    select profession, json_arrayagg(json_object('name', name)) as names
    from mytable
    group by profession
) t
```

... which generate a scalar resultset (one row and one column) with a JSON object like so:

```
{
    "Barman": [ { "name": "Gus" }, { "name": "Boris" } ],
    "Kelner": [ { "name": "Alfred" }, { "name": "Walter White" }, { "name": "Jesse Pinkman" } ]
}
```